# How to automatically update a mesh on changing parameters on THREE.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, three.js

I'm new to Threejs and to javascript in general. I'm building a mesh based on a json parameters object and it works great.

Now I'm adding some UI components (button, slider, etc) to change the json and rebuild the mesh. I'm writing some monkey-code and I'm sure it can be avoided. Now my stuff works correctly but I'm sure that the problem can be solved more elegantly.

This is my actual workflow:

1. on slider change use a callback
2. that callback calls a setter
3. the setter change the JSON parameters and rebuild the mesh

I'm sure all this can be automated by simply change the JSON and some javascript magic.

Here is the actual pseudocode:

```
sliderWidth.onChange( function(newValue) {
    MyObject3D.setWidth(newValue);
});
```

and this is a skelton of my `MyObject3D`:

```
var MyObject3D = function(parameters) {
  this.parameters = parameters;
  this.init();
};

MyObject3D.prototype.init = function() {
    var geometry = this.initGeometry();
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: this.parameters.color, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}

MyObject3D.prototype.setWidth = function(n) {
    this.parameters.width = n;
    scene.remove( this.mesh );
    this.init();
    scene.add( this.mesh );
}
```

I'm sure that with the javascript high-dinamicity and with all brand new frameworks this piece of code can be easily automated. I've looked mainly at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) and at [angular.js](https://angularjs.org). In particular d3.js seems to be perfect with the `enter-update-exit` paradigm (but I didn't find a standard way to conjugate it with Three.js) and angular for sure has to be something in it.

Any kind of advice on structure, pattern, specific use case or examples based on one of the frameworks mentioned THREE.js, d3.js, angular.js) can be enlightening. Actually I'd prefer a solution with angular.js..

Comment: Which step do you want to automate exactly?

Comment: i'd like to bind the json edit and the mesh rebuild: change the json and automatically call the rebuild mesh method.. But I'm finding a solution..

Comment: So this is a general JavaScript issue that is not specific to three.js in particular?

Comment: I think it can be resolved with some javascript magic, but I didn't tried it yet. If you find a solution.. just tell me!

Answer (score 1):

There was an excellent talk about using three.js and angular.js which exactly showcases your problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCIZoLaPJxM&t=8m5s

Im using angular directives that watch on a specific attribute and then execute some logic onchange in my projects.

```
  $scope.$watch($attrs.something, function(changedSomething){
         doSomeLogicWith(changedSomething);
  });
```